# Dependency Injection ActionFilterAttribute alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

Is there an elegant way to implement the following in a `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```
_provider = new DetailsProvider(new DetailsService(new CachingService()))
```

As you can see this does not look good. What I want to get away from, is 'newing' up these concrete classes.

Is there a nice alternative?

Comment: Do any of these classes implement interfaces?

Comment: @Alex Yeah, Each concrete class in the example has it's own interface.

Comment: You might find [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using

```
public HandlerAttribute() :
        this(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDetailsProvider>()) { }

public HandlerAttribute(IDetailsProvider detailsProvider)
{
    _detailsProvider = detailsProvider;
}
```

I am using SimpleInjector but this is interchangeable as I am using a Resolver.

You can just use whatever containers, get instance of concrete class using interface method.